# DELETE sql with composite key

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table rating with primary composite key productId and userId and two variable named productId and userId

```
"delete from rating where productId = ".$this->ms($this->productId)."
                     AND userId= ".$this->ms($this->userId);
```

what wrong with this sql syntax? i have an error message like->

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AND userId=' at line 2

Comment: first echo you sql and run it in console.

Comment: My guss is that `$this->ms($this->productId)` results in an empty string, so truly echo the command and check the syntax there.

Comment: PHP and SQL are different languages. If you have a SQL syntax error you need to look at the **generated SQL**. Said that, you're doing parameters wrong. Use prepared statements.

Comment: May be there no space before **AND**?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"delete from rating where productId = '$this->ms($this->productId)'
                     AND userId= '$this->ms($this->userId)'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call function in single quotes `''`.

Try below query:-

```
"DELETE FROM rating WHERE productId = '".$this->ms($this->productId)."'
                          AND userId= '".$this->ms($this->userId)."'";
```

Hope it will help you :)